# String / Image / ID Comparison Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, comparison

I'm having a problem somewhere in this code comparing the two images or their Id's. I'm not sure as to where I messed up exactly, but there's definitely a syntax error. I've tried many options with the string and id comparison. I'm not sure if my function or it's parameter is wrong either.

```
<img alt="" src="blah.jpg" style="height: 276px; width: 200px"  id="imgClickAndChange1" onclick="changeImage(this)" />

<img alt="" src="blah.jpg" style="height: 276px; width: 200px"   id="imgClickAndChange2" onclick="changeImage(this)" />


<script language="javascript">

function changeImage(imagePass) {

    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
    var n = num.toString();
    var numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
    var string = "/Images/folder/";
    var final = string.concat(numImg);
    if(imagePass.src === "blah.jpg") {
        var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
        var n2 = num2.toString();
        var numImg2 = n2.concat(".jpeg");
        var final2 = string.concat(numImg2);
        if(imagePass.id == "imgClickAndChange1") {
            var image = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange2');
            image.src = final;
            imagePass.src = final2;
            if(image.src == imagePass.src) {
                while(image.src == imagePass.src) {
                    num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
                    n = num.toString();
                    numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
                    final = string.concat(numImg);
                    image.src = final;
                }
            }

        }
    } else if(imagePass.id == "imgClickAndChange1") {
        var image = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange2');
        image.src = final;
        if(image.src == imagePass.src) {
            while(image.src == imagePass.src) {
                num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
                n = num.toString();
                numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
                final = string.concat(numImg):
                image.src = final;
            }

         }
    } else if (imagePass.id == "imgClickAndChange2") {
        var image = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange1');
        image.src = final;
        if(image.src == imagePass.src) {
            while(image.src == imagePass.src) {
                num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
                n = num.toString();
                numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
                final = string.concat(numImg):
                image.src = final;
            }   
        }
    }
}


</script>
```

What's it's supposed to do: You have two images on the screen. When you click an image the other image changes to a random image within a folder. While checking at the same time that the images aren't the same. (At the very start there's two of the same images on the screen, when one of these are clicked the images are to change to different images.)

---Should I do:

```
var imagePassed = document.getElementById(imagePass); //?
```

Comment: can you post a working fiddle?

Comment: @Xavdidtheshadow - I'm sorry, I don't have/use fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest issues is syntax errors, something easily avoided by using tools like [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) (either by pasting your code in there, like I did, or using a text-editor plugin). In this case, the culprit was some rogue `:` towards the bottom.

I've got a working copy of your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lrjr0zq/

Comment: Thank You very much, fixed the issue. I actually just started working with JavaScript yesterday, so wasn't really familiar with any of the tools. I'll definitely look into it.